# Powershell Script to Delete Blank Columns from CSV

Tags: mysql, powershell, csv

**Powershell Script to Delete Blank Columns from CSV**

I have a spread sheet which I'm importing into a MySQL database, the import fails because of blank columns in the spread sheet.

Is there a powershell script I can run / create that will check any given CSV file and remove blank columns?

Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,,,,
Val1,Val2,Val3,Val4

Comment: You should give an example of what you've got and what you need. A short example of what you test so far would be nice too.

Comment: Example of what I have:
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,,,,
Val1,Val2,Val3,Val4

Example of what I want:
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
Val1,Val2,Val3,Val4

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
$x = Import-Csv YourFile.csv
$f = $x[0] | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select name
$f | Add-Member -Name count -Type NoteProperty -Value 0
$f | %{
  $n = $_.Name
  $_.Count = @($x | Select $n -ExpandProperty $n | ? {$_ -ne ''}).count
}
$f = @($f | ? {$_.count -gt 0} | Select Name -expandproperty Name)

$x | Select $f | Export-Csv NewFile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

It uses Get-Member to get the column names, cycles though each one to check how many are not blank and then uses the results in a select.

Comment: I get a few error messages:

1. Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is invalid.
As far as I'm aware, this is because PS is trying to import a CSV with blank columns at the end.

After using your answer:
2. Cannot index into a null array.
3. Add-Member : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.

Comment: If your files are not valid CSVs then you will need to do a little prepossessing first to clean them up. First step is to find out why Powershell can't load them, is it because each column does not have a unique header or are some rows missing columns, do your columns contain text with embedded commas and no quoting. Then you can load a file with Get-Content, clean it probably with a regex/replace and then convert to an object using ConvertFrom=Csv.  If you can add example of your CSV to your question I could help you more.

Answer (score 0):

When I run Dave Sexton's code, I get:

```
Select-Object : Cannot convert System.Management.Automation.PSObject to one of the following 
types {System.String, System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock}.
At line:15 char:12
+ $x | Select <<<<  $f  | Export-Csv ColsRem.test.$time.csv -NoTypeInformation
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], NotSupportedException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
                  DictionaryKeyUnknownType,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand
```

I corrected this issue by adding one more line, to force each array element to be a string.

```
$x = Import-Csv YourFile.csv
$f = $x[0] | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select name
$f | Add-Member -Name count -Type NoteProperty -Value 0
$f | %{
  $n = $_.Name
  $_.Count = @($x | Select $n -ExpandProperty $n | ? {$_ -ne ''}).count
}
$f = @($f | ? {$_.count -gt 0} | Select Name -expandproperty Name)

# I could get the select to work with strings separated by commas, but the array would 
# always produce the error until I added the following line, explicitly changing the 
#values to strings.
$f = $f | Foreach-Object { "$_" } 

$x | Select $f | Export-Csv NewFile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

My import CSV contains a few hundred columns and about half likely won't be populated, so getting rid of the extra columns was necessary.  Now I just need to figure out how to counteract the unintended re-ordering of the columns into alphabetical order by name, without changing the names.

Answer (score 0):

I updated Dave Sexton's great code to not remove columns with $false and only remove empty ones

```
function Remove-EmptyColumns {

  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [PSCustomObject[]]$InputObject
  )

  $ColumnNames = $InputObject[0].PSObject.Properties.Name

  $ColumnsToRemove = foreach ($Column in $ColumnNames) {
    $ColumnValues = $InputObject.ForEach{ $_.$Column }
    # Explicitly check for $false or non-empty string
    if ($ColumnValues -contains $false -or 
        $ColumnValues.Where{ $_ -ne $null -and $_ -ne '' }) {
      # Dont remove 
    }
    else {
      $Column # Remove if all empty  
    }
  }

  return $InputObject | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty $ColumnsToRemove
}
```